# Triangulation by phase delay basic requirements

Tags: sampling, software-defined-radio

I'm trying to identify the relevant specifications/calculations for building a system (at least theoretically) to accurately triangulate the position of a 915MHz CW transmitter to within 1cm. I have an array of three yagi antennae to receive the signal which I would read in with an appropriate ADC/SDR. This whole setup would be in a room scale setup. Questions basically boils down to... how do I calculate the required sample rate for the ADC and how does that correlate the accuracy of the location? Any other tricks that might be helpful for this such as subsampling or I/Q sampling?

Comment: What is the bandwidth of the signal of interest?

Comment: over which area would you want to do that localization?

Comment: generally, you need almost *no* sampling rate if your signal is CW. It's also **literally** the worst possible waveform for localization. You really need to give us the whole picture: over which area do you want to localize (obviously, localization within 3×3m is easier than within 3×3 km…), how much power does your transmitter emit, what's the noise figure of your receive chains, what does your channel look like (especially temporally!)…

Comment: If I weren't to use CW, then the bandwidth would be 26MHz. That is part of the math that I'm not clear on, if I modulate 915MHz then how do I calculate spatial accuracy based on sample rate? This would be room scale but let's say 3 meter cube. Regarding transmitter power and noise, I'd be most interested in the calculations/equations that take this into account, but otherwise the ideal case would help me wrap my head around the problem.